# IfxPy will not run SQL statement after modification

Tags: python, informix

I'm running Ubunutu 20.04 LTs on a server and have the following for my Python code.  IfxPy is installed correctly and if I modify the SQL statement to change the table name, the program will run.  However, if I change the WHERE criteria, the system simply returns "0" & "Done"

```
import IfxPy

ConStr="Driver={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER};SERVER=db;DATABASE=records;host=myhost;service=9088;protocol=onsoctcp"

conn=IfxPy.connect(ConStr,"Username","Password")

sql = "SELECT * FROM public.daylog WHERE sernum < 40"
stmt = IfxPy.exec_immediate(conn,sql)
tu = IfxPy.fetch_assoc(stmt)
#print(tu)
rc = 0

str = []
while tu != False:
    rc += 1
    print(tu)
    tu = IfxPy.fetch_assoc(stmt)


print(rc)
IfxPy.free_result(stmt)
IfxPy.free_stmt(stmt)
IfxPy.close(conn)

print("Done")
```

If I run it the first time, it will return the dictionary that I am looking for to get my program running.   However, if I change the SQL statement to be:

```
SELECT * FROM public.daylog WHERE sernum > 60
```

I get nothing back from this.  I have an ODBC connection to the database as well, so I've tried testing it that way and seeing the data on the backend.  I made sure to include the IfxPy.free_result and IfxPy.free_stmt functions.

Comment: Can you produce example data, presumably with at least two rows in the `daylog` table, one with `sernum` of 39 or smaller and one with `sernum` of 61 or larger, and demonstrate the effect?  It seems unlikely that the server is misinterpreting the queries; such a simple change of criteria is very unlikely to cause trouble.  Looking for extreme possibilities, have you run `oncheck` on the table — or asked the DBA to do it?  It probably isn't that, but if there is a corrupt index, it could be causing the trouble.

Comment: We may end up having to look at the data transmitted between the client (Python code) and the server — this can be done without editing the code.  We may end up wanting to look at query plans via `SET EXPLAIN ON`.  But, a priori, the change you described should not mean 'valid data' from `sernum < 40` and 'invalid data' from `sernum > 60`.  It is, in all honesty, more likely that there is no data satisfying the `sernum > 60` condition.  If you have access to DB-Access, you could use that to check the results too.

Comment: There is data in the sernum field as with the ODBC connection I can see the complete table through MS Access.  I wasnt sure if maybe due to the fact that it iterates through the returns in each one if maybe there is a conflict with the connection which is why I close the connection at the end.  I'm going to try re-running what was giving no results when I'm back in on monday and see if may there is an issue with either free_stmt or free_result and see if maybe its an issue with IfxPy.

Comment: I tried your code with a dummy table and both selects (`<40` and `>60`) return the expected data so maybe there is something going on on the server side.   You can get a SQLIDEBUG trace (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/setting-sqlidebug-client-side) to check what the server sends to the client (`sqliprint -tuple %sqlifile%`)